# Multi-level Numbering in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following excel file [image]

The user will enter the number of the levels (3 levels in the example) then using sequence function it will be showed in the level columns colored light blue automatically. Then, the user should enter the sub-clause next to each level. My desired outcome is I would like the Level & Sub-Clause 1 column to be filled with the following list based on the user entry as mentioned before:

- 1
- 1.1
- 2
- 2.1
- 2.2
- 2.3
- 3
- 3.1
- 3.2

is it possible?

Comment: Sure it's possible. Which do you prefer, formula or VBA?

Comment: I'm more familiar with formulas, but I don't mind to learn about VBA. Could you please explain both ways? I would be very thankful & grateful. If that will take you a lot of time and effort, its okay to explain one way to do that. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With TOCOL,MAKEARRAY inside a LET with FILTER to remove the blanks:

```
=LET(
    r,B1,
    l,B4#,
    sc,C4:INDEX(C:C,4+r-1),
    cl,TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(r,MAX(sc+1),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b=1,INDEX(l,a),IF(b-1>INDEX(sc,a),"",INDEX(l,a)&"."&b-1)))),3),
    FILTER(cl,cl<>""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("-",,BYROW(B6:INDEX(C:C,MAX(ROW(B6#))),LAMBDA(br,TEXTJOIN("-",,INDEX(br,,1),INDEX(br,,1)&"."&SEQUENCE(INDEX(br,,2)))))),,"-")
```

[image]

Edit: forgot about the single level at first. Updated the formula and screenshot to include it.